# How to reduce the code in ado.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I am using 2 methods

```
public int InsertEmpDetails(EmployeeViewModel objemp)
    {
        try
        {

            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_InsertEmployeedetails", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", objemp.Name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Salary", objemp.Salary);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeptId", objemp.DeptId);
            result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

And another method is

```
public int SaveStudentMarks(StudentViewModel objstu)
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_SaveStudentDetails", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StuName", objstu.Name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", objstu.Age);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@M1", objstu.M1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@M2", objstu.M2);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@M3", objstu.M3);
            result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
   }
```

In this both are having same code but different parameters.how to reduce the code

Comment: Both are same ?i can see different names of procedures.

Comment: use SQLHelper class. Find more info about it at http://www.totaldotnet.com/sub/custom-sqlhelper-class-in-csharp-for-your-database-interaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Use Another Method Are class like

```
public static int ExecuteNonQuery(SqlCommand cmd,CommandType cmdType,string cmdText)        
      {           
        if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        con.Open();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText =cmdText;
        cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
        return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
```

And replace the Above methods like

```
try
{
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", objemp.Name);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Salary", objemp.Salary);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeptId", objemp.DeptId);
  result = DataHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd,CommandType.StoredProcedure,"sp_InsertEmployeedetails");            
}
```

Like Replace 2nd method Also

Comment: Is this the solution you have found or you looking for solution like this ?

Comment: No i wrote the solution